# is it possible to access xml data as a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, xml

I have a basic XML file that I load in my PHP using

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
```

I want to be able to access my data using syntax something similar to:

```
$xml[0]['from'];
$xml['note']['from'];
$xml['from']['email'];
```

I know I can access the data using this:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
}
```

However, this is NOT a preferred method, and I would like to use syntax similar to multidimensional arrays.

Using APIs from many different websites, this is generally how I would access XML, however, I can't seem to do it with my own using `simplexml_load_file("file.xml");`

I know this is very simple but is there something I'm missing? Please help! Thanks in advance

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>
    <name>Jani</name>
    <email>email@email.com</email>
</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: can u please explain that what you want in this variables: $xml[0]['from'];
$xml['note']['from'];
$xml['from']['email'];

Comment: is the note node will come only once or it will be repeated????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its not a perfect solution for you but it might help you for your problem.

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>
    <name>Jani</name>
    <email>email@email.com</email>
</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("new.xml");  

    $webroot="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    $doc->load( $webroot.'/new.xml' );

    $note = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "note" );
    $final_arr = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($note as $note)
    {
        $to = $note->getElementsByTagName( "to" );
        $to = $to->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $final_arr[$i]['to'] = $to;

        $from = $note->getElementsByTagName( "from" );
        foreach($from as $from)
        {
            $name = $from->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
            $name = $name->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $final_arr[$i]['from']['name'] = $name;
            $email = $from->getElementsByTagName( "email" );
            $email = $email->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $final_arr[$i]['from']['email'] = $email;
        }


        $heading = $note->getElementsByTagName( "heading" );
        $heading = $heading->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $final_arr[$i]['heading'] = $heading;

        $body = $note->getElementsByTagName( "body" );
        $body = $body->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $final_arr[$i]['body'] = $body;
        $i++;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($final_arr);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: Wow avinash you code with amazing speed!  Thank you so much for this solution.  I really appreciate it and will certainly be putting it to good use!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unless you are parsing the xml file yourself, you cannot do this.  Any attempt to access one of the nodes will most likely return a DOM error saying that it cannot be converted to a string.

You can take a look at this post:  http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/1364-turn-xml-into-2-dimensional-array.

If it is something you really need to do, you will probably need to do it yourself with an additional step, like creating a function or class to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

"and I would like to use syntax *similar* to multidimensional arrays." - I don't know if it's similar enough: `$notes->note[0]->to;` as in

```
<?php
$notes = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<notes>
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>
        <name>Jani</name>
        <email>email@email.com</email>
    </from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don\'t forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
  <note>...</note>
  <note>...</note>
</notes>');
echo $notes->note[0]->to;
```